# Item vs Container.DataItem vs Eval

Tags: asp.net, performance, data-binding

I migrated from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.5, and I have the option to switch from `Eval` and `Container.DataItem` to `ItemType` + `Item` everywhere. But what about performance? How `Item` is implemented internally? Is it based on `Container.DataItem` or `Eval` or something else?

Answer (score 3):

### Update

According to the following link, Container.DataItem will use reflection at run time, ItemType will save this step at run time, So ItemType should be more performant than Container.DataItem

[What's New in ASP.NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20160621111228/http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new)

---

Previously when working with template controls such as GridView, you would declare item with syntax similar to the follwing : `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %>`
with this syntax, easy to mistake such as a mistake in typeing and IDE doesnot knowthe type you are binding to until runtime.
ASP.Net 4.5 solves these issues by allowing you to specify the type of the item
the syntax will be as the follwing `<%# Item.ID>`
This is the main differ between two syntaxs.

About how this implement in .net 4.5
first you impelement class

> (I will worked with GridView as example)

```
public class SalesPerson
{
  public string SalesPersonID { get; set; }
  public string     FirstName { get; set; }
  public string      LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Next you determine ItemType

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false"
              DataKeyNames="SalesID"
              SelectMethod="yourGetMethod"
              UpdateMethod="yourUpdateMethod"
              ItemType="SalesPerson">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
                   Text='<%# Item.SalesID %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"
                   Text='<%# Item.SalesID %>'></asp:Label>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**conclusion** *the Container.DataItem is replaced in .net 4.5 to ItemType to solve mistakes issue as typing issue and with ItemType compiler can detect if any mistakes as typing mistakes*

Comment: So... `Item` calls `Eval` and have same very bad performance?

Comment: According to the following link, ItemType save a step that will not use the reflection as  Container.DataItem,
So using ItemType should be more performance than Container.DataItem

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097386